# Open Facebook links with Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, url

When I receive a http Facebook link, I have the option to choose my browsers but not the Facebook app, is there a way to force it? Is it the normal behavior?

Comment: Do you have the official [Facebook app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. I thought it would show as option like the browsers.

Comment: It has never done this for me. Twitter, Google+ etc do, but facebook always went to the browser. Just tried it on Galaxy S4, Nexus 4, HTC Desire X, HTC One and a Nexus 7 now and the same on all. Fresh installed and logged in Facebook app too.

Comment: I'll try some third party apps to see if it works like that. Why wouldn't Facebook links open in Facebook app. I don't see a reason.

Comment: Tried some apps and no one was capable to open urls... Seems like Facebook doesn't want us to open its links in a app.

Comment: Facebook doesn't care. This is very annoying. Pretty much every app can open links related to them regardless of schema. Except Facebook with devs who are stubbornly expecting everyone to use a non-standard schema, rendering almost all http-based Facebook links in the web unopenable on the app. /rant

Answer (score 2):

> Is it normal behavior?

Facebook app only handles specialized URL scheme `fb://` and nothing more, so any standard HTTP/S Facebook links (`http://` or `https://`) will be ignored by the app. So, yes, unfortunately this is normal.

> Is there a way to force it?

As of current writing, until their developers implement a filter to handle HTTP protocol, there is no way to do that from their apps.

It might be possible for a 3rd-party app to fix this with a workaround (e.g. [Open Link in App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.snarfed.android.openinapp) app, as mentioned from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/67106/44325), but it seems currently it's not working, possibly due to [change in FB protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24547437/2821954)).

Answer (score 1):

The [Facebook app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) on Android now supports [deeplinking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html). So your `http://` and `https://` should work. Within the Facebook app as well as from other apps.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @ADTC Tap on any Facebook link, and the OS will open it in the FB native app (if installed)

Comment: No it doesn't do that. The link only opens in the browser, as if there is no app installed. (I have the Facebook app installed.)

Comment: Works for me on Android 6 and 7 both. On Galaxy S7 and Pixel, both.