# Inside Facebook app, how to set YouTube links to be opened on YouTube app?

Tags: facebook, youtube

How to set YouTube links to be opened on YouTube app on Android in Facebook app?

I saw some videos how to do it but they're too old.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force links to open in the app, not the default browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37549/force-links-to-open-in-the-app-not-the-default-browser)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/194218/131553